Are there any nervous system diseases/disorders/conditions that selectively target glial cells but not neurons?
Anyone know of any nervous system diseases/disorders/conditions that selectively target glial cells but not neurons? Maybe the neurons get damaged too as a result of the glial cells getting damaged given that glial cells are needed for neuronal function, but I'm looking for a condition in which the glial cells are the ones that are targeted (if such a condition should exist).
Thanks.

Given that glia are necessary for neuronal function, I don't think it's reasonable to expect that any disease that damages glial cells would not also affect neurons.

Welcome Fast[...]. Remember to show your prior research when posting a question. It's worth reading the [ask] section to get the basics of our requirements.

@BryanKrause good point... I've changed my question a bit to reflect your point.

@JiminyCricket. What do you mean by prior research?

The results of your searches of relevant documentation on the web, what you discovered there, so we can judge your current level of understanding and how to pitch an answer. We encourage self-learning on the science-sites. Plus it represents a good grounding for future enquirers in the available material and vocabulary.

@JiminyCricket. Gotya, will do.

A classic example would be a demyelinating disorder like multiple sclerosis.
Gliomas are glial cell tumors.
Other complex chronic disorders like Alzheimer's disease may principally involve glial cells but the overall disease mechanisms are too poorly understood and may be too complex for a simple "cause, effect" relationship.

Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't think of multiple sclerosis. That was an obvious one. Thanks for your reply!

I forgot that with multiple sclerosis the oligodendrocytes themselves are being attacked and not just the myelin.

@FastBallooningHead Even if it were only the myelin targeted, myelin is effectively part of oligodendrocytes or Schwann cells, an extension of their cell membranes.

Oh yeah you're right, I forgot about that, good point.


Besides Multiple Sclerosis, there are some disorders that specifically attack astrocytes, like Neuromyelitis Optica, Devic’s Disease, and Alexander's Disease.

We have some diseases that specifically harm oligodendrocytes and Schwann cells, like Leukodystrophies.


3)We also have something called HIV-Associated Neurocognitive Disorders (HAND), which specifically attacks Microglia and astrocytes.

Astrocytes seem to be glial cells, @JiminyCricket. The connection is maybe not made crystal clear by this answer, but it seems like a relevant answer.

I really should have looked that up before commenting. @StevenJeuris Radnyee, please do take our [tour] and refer to the [help] at your leisure to get the hang of how we work.

@Radnyee Sarvadnya Thanks for your reply. Very helpful information. Never heard of the three diseases you listed in # 1 - will read about them.
